# Is there a context-free language that can produce all the composite numbers?

Tags: context-free-grammar, natural-numbers

I have a proof that there is no context-free language that can produce all (and only) prime numbers. But, as context-free languages are not closed under complement, I have not found that there isn't possible to express the language L that produces all composite numbers.

For all purposes, numbers are in unary and the terminal symbol is 1.

---

The proof that there is no CFL that produces all prime numbers and no composite numbers I got [here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/437316/64969) (in portuguese). I just used the pumping lema for CFL:

Take a prime number $N \in L$. $N$ is such that it can be expressed as a word concatenation of $u v w x y$, where $\left|v x\right| \ge 1$ and $\left|v w x\right| \le p$. So any word in the form of $u v^n w x^n y \in L, n \ge 0$.

Therefore, there are two possibilities:

- $\left|u w y\right| = 0$, or
- $\left|u w y\right| \gt 0$

If the first case is true, than for $n = 2$ I got $u v^2 w x^2 y$ also in $L$, but as $\left|u w y\right| = 0$, than it implies that $2N \in L$, so $L$ produces a non-prime number.

For the other case, if I pick $n = \left|u w y\right|$ I got the word $u v^{u+w+y} w x^{u+w+y} y$ that should be also in $L$. So, as this is a number in unary notation, that implies that $u + v\cdot\left(u + w + y\right) + w + x\cdot\left(u + w + y\right) + y$ should also be in $L$. So, that implies that $\left(u + w + y\right)\cdot\left(v + x + 1\right)$ is also a prime number, but it is indeed a non-prime.

> In this final paragraph, I ommited some $\left|u\right|$ for the sake of readability, but intention should be clear to the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the pumping lemma, the lengths of words generated by a context free grammar are a [semilinear set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_arithmetic_progression#semilinear_set). If the alphabet has one symbol only, that means the language is regular. But then it's complement (i.e. the primes) would be regular too, contradiction.